# How to change the color state in Home Assistant

Tags: home-assistant

I have the following in configuration.yaml, how do change the icon color according to state?

```
  washing_machine_running:
    friendly_name: "Washing Machine Running"
    value_template: >
      {% if states('sensor.shelly_bathroom_washing_machine_power') != 'unknown' %}
        {% set power_consumption = states('sensor.shelly_bathroom_washing_machine_power') | float %}
        {% if power_consumption > 3 %}
          Running ({{ power_consumption }} W)
        {% else %}
          Not Running ({{ power_consumption }} W)
        {% endif %}
      {% else %}
        Not Running
      {% endif %}
    icon_template: >-
      {% if is_state('sensor.washing_machine_running', 'Running') or states('sensor.washing_machine_running').startswith('Running') %}
        mdi:washing-machine
      {% else %}
        mdi:washing-machine-off
      {% endif %}
```